# Nodejs Module async.series not working (later function excutes before previous function)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3u2i.png)

[Server.js result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuV5h.png)

My code is this

```
app.post('/get_page_data', function(req, res) {
function find (i,documents)
{
    Item_data.find({item_name:documents[i].item_name}).exec(function (err,asd){
            console.log(documents[i].item_name+": found");
            console.log(asd[0].like);

    }
    )
}
Page_data.find().lean().exec(function (err, documents) {
var doc=documents;

async.series([
// 1st
function(done){
    for(var i=0;i<documents.length;i++)
{

    find(i,doc);
    done()
}
},
// 2nd
function(done){
    console.log("1");
    console.log(doc);
    console.log("2");
    res.end(JSON.stringify(doc));
    console.log("3");
    done()
}
]);


}
)});
```

I'll introduce my code simply
when ajax called /get_page_data
i bring the pages data (page1,page2,page3 ...) in documents
every page has a item_name but pages data does not have the "like" data
so i find the value of "like" in the other collection(Item_data) by the same item name and put the "like" in the pages data documents

but this makes me crazy
the pages data is sent before i put the like value

so i read about the non blocking io and async blahblah...
and i found the async module. And used it.
But as you can see the pictures above, they're not working

(before trying async moudle they didn't work neither)

### I don't know why res.end part excutes previously and Please tell me the solution of this situation Thank you for reading

[image: updated result]

Comment: Well you're supposed to call `done` only when all the asynchronous actions (in your case, `find`) have taken place. If you call it immediately, the next function will be executed right then as well.

Comment: @Bergi as i said when i used them without the asyn module they didn't work neither. Same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

put the done thing inside the aysn function and call the done when the index value

```
    app.post('/get_page_data', function(req, res) {
        function find (i,documents,cb)
        {
            Item_data.find({item_name:documents[i].item_name}).exec(function (err,asd){
                    console.log(documents[i].item_name+": found");
                    console.log(asd[0].like);
                    console.log(i +"/"+ documents.length);
                    documents[i]["like"]=asd[0].like;
                    if(i==documents.length-1) cb();
                        //call done() when the index reached maximum
            
            })
            
        }
    Page_data.find().lean().exec(function (err, documents) {
        var doc=documents;
        
    async.series([
        // 1st
        function(done){
            for(var i=0;i<documents.length;i++)
        {
            find(i,doc,done); //put the done thing inside the function
        }
        },
        // 2nd
        function(done){
            console.log("1");
            console.log(doc);
            console.log("2");
            res.end(JSON.stringify(doc));
            console.log("3");
            done()
        }
    ]);
```

[image]

working properly

Comment: You just should use `async.each` instead of that for-loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your `find` function is doing an asynchronous call, so the `done()` is being called before it returns any data. 
You should move it inside the inner find callback.

Edit: Using `async.each` instead of `async.series` directly.

```
app.post('/get_page_data', function(req, res) {
  function find (document, cb) {
    Item_data.find({item_name:document.item_name}).exec(function (err,asd) {
      console.log(document.item_name+": found");
      console.log(asd[0].like);
      cb();
    })
  }

  Page_data.find().lean().exec(function (err, documents) {
    var doc=documents;
    async.each(documents,
    // 1st
    find(document, cb), 
    // 2nd
    function() {
      console.log("1");
      console.log(doc);
      console.log("2");
      res.end(JSON.stringify(doc));
      console.log("3");
    });
 }
)});
```

PS: there's also a lot of things that you should improve in that code. But that way it should work.

Comment: i just updated as you suggested. It worked but! just one loop worked not else ... (look at the updated picture bellow)

Comment: oh! i found the answer based on your idea not just cb(); but  if(i==documents.length-1) cb(); worked many thanks!

Comment: You are right, I missed that loop. I'll update the answer considering that.
Anyway you should consider using promises for this kind of things, or even another option could be to use another async function for the loop.